# How to trigger the method on click of custom link in angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have a scenario where I need to create a  tag from TS and i need to capture the click event if someone click on  tag

In Html

```
<p [innerHtml]="textField"></p>

<button (click)="generateLink()">click</button>
```

In Ts

```
textField = 'Hello click button for link';

  generateLink() {
    this.textField = `${this.textField} <a href="#" onclick="update()">click me</a>`;
  }

  update(){
    console.log('click me is clicked')
  }
```

Here whenever click me is click I need to trigger update method.
link to stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zhutvz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Please anyone let me know how to achieve it.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It feels that in this case using `*ngIf` would be the right idea to use here. In angular it does not compile HTML on the fly, like how angularjs used to do using [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#:%7E:text=Overview,matching%20DOM%20elements%20to%20directives) API.

What I mean is `innerHTML` tag will just do the work of rendering the HTML inside DOM, it won't enable any binding there (you can not call `update` method there). Hence you can use `*ngIf` directive to show and hide DOM conditionally.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="showLink">
  {{textField}}
  <a href="#" (click)="update()">click me</a>
</ng-container>

<button (click)="generateLink()">click</button>
```

**TS**

```
  showLink = false;

  generateLink() {
    this.showLink = true;
  }
```

[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wga1a5)

---

An alternative way to generate link without using `*ngIf`, is by using combination of `ng-template` and `ng-container` to generate and inject template manually.

**HTML**

```
<ng-container #links></ng-container>

<button (click)="generateLinkFromTemplate()">another click</button>

<ng-template #link>
  {{ textField }}
  <a href="#" (click)="update()">click me</a>
</ng-template>
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChild('links', { read: ViewContainerRef }) links: ViewContainerRef;
@ViewChild('link', { read: TemplateRef }) link: TemplateRef<any>;

generateLinkFromTemplate() {
  this.links.createEmbeddedView(this.link);
}
```

[Another Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-einawu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I need to create <a> tag from Ts file and then i need to capture the click event of the <a>

Comment: @acchu may I know why you don't want to do it other way? (if you do that way you won't get access to `update` function)